# validation accuracy is highly fluctuating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Following is the VGG16 implementation for my classification problem(COVID,pneumonia,Normal).

```
# importing necessary packages
import cv2,os 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("New_1300_dataset.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("DataSet")

datapath = "/content/DataSet/New_1300_dataset"
categories = os.listdir(datapath)
label_cat = []
for i in range(len(categories)):
    label_cat.append(i)

print(categories)
print(label_cat)

# initializing the parameters like initial learning rate, number of epochs, batch size
initial_LR = 1e-3
num_epochs = 50
b_size = 32

# iterating through all images and appending them to list
print("[Information] Loading All the Images..")
data = []
labels = []

for category in categories:
    path = os.path.join(datapath, category)
    img_names = os.listdir(path)
    for img in img_names:
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(64, 64))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = preprocess_input(image)
        
        data.append(image)
        labels.append([category])

# one hot encoding the output .. 
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
labels = encoder.fit_transform(labels)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.1, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# Normalizing the data (i.e.. zero mean and unit variance)
mean = np.mean(x_train, axis = (0,1,2,3))
std = np.std(x_train, axis = (0,1,2,3))

x_train = (x_train-mean)/(std + 1e-7)
x_test = (x_test-mean)/(std + 1e-7)
```

## defining the model

```
`model = models.Sequential([
layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(64,64,3)),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu') ,
layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Dropout(0.5),

layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Dropout(0.5),

layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Dropout(0.5),

layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Dropout(0.5),

layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Activation('relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Dropout(0.5),

layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

opt = RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-4) 
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I applied batchnormalization after every conv2D and dropout of 0.5 after maxpooling to avoid overfitting.  Each class of my data i.e covid,pneumonia and healthy lung has 1300 images each. And following is the accuracy

[image]

as you can see the valaccuracy is fluctuating very much. I tried using different optimizers like Adam, SGD but in that case I am getting constant val_accuracy of 33.24 and it is not changing. How can I improve this? Thanks in advance. I also varied the learning rates of the optimizers but its of no use.

Comment: can u please tell me why do u have 3 layers dense at the end which are relu-relu-softmax ? your question is somehow like an over-fit problem i think.  have u tried with data augmentation ?

Comment: also I am keeping 0.1 validation split and 0.1 test split.

Comment: 3 layers because we have to predict COVID,healthy or pneumonia so 3 classes

Comment: that makes no sense  (the thing of the 3 layers)... the variance is probably due to your validation test size, probably you have very few samples

Comment: I am sorry I thought he was asking why 3 at the dense layer end. The above code is complete implementation of VGG16. You can check it out in the internet. And you want we to keep validation split to 0.2 then? But the thing is I am having 1300 images each class. If I keep more split for validation we will have less data for training? Anyway I will try your suggestion

Comment: This is not a programming question and doesn't belong on this site. Suggest you post on another SE site, like Cross Validated or Data Science.

Comment: Did you use this https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/prashant268/chest-xray-covid19-pneumonia?resource=download?

Comment: Actually no, i have no idea this was on kaggle i actually downloaded from various sites and created the dataset on my own.